# event defaults to flash.events and not external libaray in flash

Tags: flash, multi-touch

SO i am trying to access the TOUCH_DOWN and TOUCH_UP constants of the tuio library through the TouchEvent method however flash keeps defaulting the TouchEvent method to the flash.events TouchEvent and i can't figure out why. has anyone else had this problem maybe with another external library?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean "defaulting" at compile time, or defaulting at runtime?

Try using the fully qualified name of the TouchEvent class, like so: `org.tuio.TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN`, or explicitly use `import org.tuio.TouchEvent;`.

Also, the tuio event will only be dispatched by an `org.tuio.TouchContainer`.

And this I can only guess, since I don't know the source code, but if the constants use the same `String` value (i.e. `"touchDown"`) as `flash.events.TouchEvent`, listener methods for both events will be triggered at runtime.  So you can always only listen to one event with the same `String` value at a time.